# Input type number value is eraed after 300ms if contains a dot (decimal separator)

Tags: javascript

I have a number input field: user writes down the number and after 300ms, if not a valid number, the input value is erased.
The problem is that if a user writes a dot (decimals separator) and is not fast enough to insert decimals, the number is erased too (please see script included)

`console.log()` shows that inputs like "123." are considered empty values (and parseFloat returns NaN, of course).

Is there an easy solution to treat numbers like "123." as still valid? Thanks

```js
function delay(callback, ms) {
    var timer = 0;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            callback.apply(context, args);
        }, ms || 0);
    };
}

$('#test').on('input', delay(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    
    var value = el.val();
    console.log(value, parseFloat(value));
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || parseFloat(value) <= 0) {
      value = '';
    }
   
    el.val(value);
}, 300));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="test" value="" min="0" step="0.01">
```

Comment: why do you expect someone to be able to enter a number in 300ms?  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: This seems overly complicated; I would use the `pattern` attribute and make the decimal places optional with a regular expression.

Comment: Don't use `isNaN(parseFloat(value))` (which, btw, would also allow "Infinity" as input!) if you want to allow partial input. Use a regex pattern, such as `/^[0-9.]$/.test(value)`  instead.

Comment: `parseFloat("123.")` doesn't return `NaN`.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It's actually a debouncing function, so it's just limiting the time between keystrokes to 300ms, not the whole entry.

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to validate input while the user is typing, it makes it hard for them to correct typos. Wait for them to leave the field or submit the form.